# Grails 3 and Mlab MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, grails

I am trying to connect my simple POC grails app to my Mlab MongoDB database. I am able to connect via the terminal just fine. But my grails app keeps trying to connect to localhost:127.0.0.1:27017. However my connection string in application.yml point to my mlab instance. Any ideas on this?

Here is the stack trace:

ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using? did you take a look on 'Advanced Configuration' in http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/#advancedConfig ?

Comment: 3.2.1. This appears to be a bug. Tracking down more info.

Answer (score 0):

Grails 3 has a good support for mongodb. You can connect to mongodb using below configuration in application.yml file.

```
grails:
  mongodb:
    url: mongodb://username:password@xxxxxxxx:15340/demoapp
```

Also make sure you have the below dependency on build.gradle file.

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.1.3'
```